# Castle Windsor: get informed by the container after any object was resolved

Tags: castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor as DI Container and have following question:

Is it possible to get informed by the container each time, any object was created by the container and get a reference to this object?

I want to check after each resolve, if the resolved object implements a special interface (e.g. IEmergencyStop). I want to register this object at a special service (EmergencyStopHelper).

Following an example:

```
interface IEmergencyStop
{
   void Stop();
}

interface IMotor : IEmergencyStop
{
   void Run();
}

class Motor : IMotor
{
}

class EmergencyStopHelper
{
   List<IEmergencyStop> emergencyStopList = new List<IEmergencyStop>();

   public void Register(IEmergencyStop aClass)
   { 
      emergencyStopList.Add(aClass); 
   }

   public void StopAll() => emergencyStopList.ForEach( x => x.Stop());
}


container.Register(Component.For<IMotor>().ImplementedBy<Motor>().LifestlyleTransient());
container.Register(Component.For<EmergencyStopHelper>());

// TODO: any magic code which calls EmergencyStopHelper.Register(...)
// after following resolve

IMotor aMotor = container.Resolve<IMotor>();

var emergencyStop = container.Resolve<EmergencyStopHelper>();
emergencyStop.StopAll();
```

Comment: You can use a [SubResolver](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/resolvers.md) to achieve this.

Comment: Hi Rabban, I think a SubResolver is not what I need. Using a SubResolver I have to resolve the dependency by myself. But I do not want to resolve it, I will only be informed, that any object was created and then check, if this object implements a special interface.